# How to crop and download facebook profile image with image upload class?

Tags: php

I have implemented functionality of facebook login & registration in ionic application and need to crop and download user's facebook profile image file to the server.  I am able to download user's profile picture but how do I crop and download image file (in 3 sizes) with class.upload.php ?  I have implemented this functionality in simple user registration but I don't know how to use class.upload.php with facebook profile image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution in [this class](https://github.com/eventviva/php-image-resize)

**Example :**

include 'ImageResize.php';

$imagePrefix = time() . rand(0, 99);
$vImage = $imagePrefix . '.jpg';
$path1 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/your/path/to/original/';
$path2 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/your/path/to/110_110/';
$path3 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/your/path/to/90_100/';
$path4 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/your/path/to/70_70/';
$url = '';

$image = new \Eventviva\ImageResize($url);
$image->save($path1 . $vImage)
        ->crop(70, 70)
        ->save($path4 . $vImage)
        ->crop(110, 110)
        ->save($path2 . $vImage)
        ->crop(100, 90)
        ->save($path3 . $vImage);